# What is the best way in python to create a confusion matrix out of an already aggregated table with counts of actual labels and predicted labels

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

What is the best / fastest way to create a confusion matrix in python if the data is available in the following format:

```
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| Actual Label | Predicted Label | Count Occurrences |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| A            | A               | 200               |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| B            | B               | 150               |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| C            | D               | 15                |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| X            | Y               | 5                 |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
| ...          | ...             | ...               |
+--------------+-----------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you have the dataframe in the following form:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Actual Label': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Predicted Label': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'],
    'Count Occurences': [200, 150, 100, 150, 50, 100, 70, 80]
})
```

which will look like this:

```
  Actual Label Predicted Label  Count Occurences
0            A               A               200
1            A               B               150
2            A               C               100
3            A               D               150
4            B               B                50
5            B               C               100
6            C               D                70
7            D               D                80
```

Then you can use the `.pivot_table()` function to create a matrix-like table:

```
df = df.pivot_table(values='Count Occurences', index='Actual Label', columns='Predicted Label')
```

that is similar to a confusion matrix:

```
Predicted Label      A      B      C      D
Actual Label                               
A                200.0  150.0  100.0  150.0
B                  NaN   50.0  100.0    NaN
C                  NaN    NaN    NaN   70.0
D                  NaN    NaN    NaN   80.0
```

If you want to get rid of the column and index names, just use the `values` attribute to get the `numpy` array with the dataframe values only. You might also want to use `.fillna()` to get rid of the `NaN` values and replace them with 0:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
print(df.values)

# Output

[[200. 150. 100. 150.]
 [  0.  50. 100.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  70.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  80.]]
```

---

**EDIT**

There might be cases where not all actual labels have been predicted and some might, therefore, be missing. An example would be:

```
  Actual Label Predicted Label  Count Occurences
0            A               A               200
1            A               B               150
2            A               C               100
3            B               B               150
4            B               C                50
5            C               D               100
6            D               D                70
7            E               A                80
```

Observe that label `E` was never predicted. The above code will generate a matrix like this:

```
[[200. 150. 100.   0.]
 [  0. 150.  50.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0. 100.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  70.]
 [ 80.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

In such cases, you can manually add all columns that are missing to create a confusion matrix:

```
missing_cols = [col for col in df.index if col not in df.columns]

for col in missing_cols:
    df[col] = 0

# This will ensure that the index and columns have the same order
df = df[df.index.values]
```

and get

```
[[200. 150. 100.   0.   0.]
 [  0. 150.  50.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0. 100.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.  70.   0.]
 [ 80.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Your solution seems to work. However, I do have an imbalanced numer of unique values of 'Actual Labels' (df_initial['Actual Label'].nunique = 17) and 'Predicted Labels' ((df_initial['Predicted Label'].nunique = 15)). So if I use your solution I get a 17x15 matrix, where I indeed need a 17x17 matrix (if I understood the matter of confusion matrices correctly). Do you have an Idea how to tackle this issue with your beautifully simple solution?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover this case as well. I couldn't come up with something more elegant than to add the missing columns. But it will solve the problem. I also found something maybe more elegant to generate the matrix in the first place. Just check it out.

Comment: Simple, elegant, fast, I really appreciate your answer :) keep the good work! Best Regards

Comment: I realized that if you just add the columns it might break the order between the index and the columns. So the result would not be a real confusion matrix. I added the statement after the `for` loop to guarantee the right order. I think now everything should be covered.