# What is the tidyr pivot_wider equivalent to the index argument in Python's pivot_table?

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr, confusion-matrix, sparklyr

In this question ([What is the best way in python to create a confusion matrix out of an already aggregated table with counts of actual labels and predicted labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816393/what-is-the-best-way-in-python-to-create-a-confusion-matrix-out-of-an-already-ag)), it is relatively straightforward to get a confusion matrix of two columns of data by pivoting it using the following function:

```
df = df.pivot_table(values='Count Occurences', index='Actual Label', columns='Predicted Label')
```

How would one go about this in R using `tidyr::pivot_wider`? I have tried several permutations of the following code on a `sparklyr` table, but it always results in an error (for example, that the names are not unique).

```
df %>% select(x, y) %>%
group_by(x, y) %>%
count %>%
pivot_wider(id_cols = 'x', names_from = 'y', values_from = 'n')
```

A solution in R which does work involves the `xtabs` function, e.g.:

```
df %>% select(x, y) %>%
group_by(x, y) %>%
count %>%
collect %>%
xtabs(formula = n ~ x + y, data=.)
```

Is there a solution using `pivot_wider`?

The following is example data (copied from the linked question) in the same format one would expect after the `group_by` and `count` operations are completed on `x` and `y`.

```
df = data.frame(
'x'= c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D'),
'y'= c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'),
'n'= c(200, 150, 100, 150, 50, 100, 70, 80))
```

If one runs the `pivot_wider(names_from = c('x', 'y'), values_from = 'n')` command on this data, the output is

```
    # A tibble: 1 × 8
    A_A   A_B   A_C   A_D   B_B   B_C   C_D   D_D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1   200   150   100   150    50   100    70    80
```

Which is not a confusion matrix nor equivalent to Python's output. When run on a sparklyr table of the exact same data, the error message is:

```
Error in `arrange()`:
ℹ In argument: `__row_num_79a4dd05_ce72_4873_967f_5d5ac9e9f66b`
Caused by error:
! Object `__row_num_79a4dd05_ce72_4873_967f_5d5ac9e9f66b` not found.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: You should consider providing the data and then we can help

Comment: The argument is `id_cols`, not `ids_from`, so try that. If your table only has a few columns, you can also omit `id_cols`, and it will use all columns not listed in `names_from` or `values_from` as the ID / index columns.

Comment: Thanks @zephryl, that was a typo on my end when making this question, my code had id_cols in it. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Onyambu, I would like my code to generically support data that has either numeric (but not continuous) values or categoricals. I think the data in the answer to the linked question is sufficient for testing code that would work. Please let me know if you disagree. The actual data I'm working with is proprietary and quite large.

Comment: You still need to PROVIDE DATA. Explaining what DATA is ,is not sufficient. Post data with atleast 5 observations

Comment: @Onyambu I have added example data as requested.

Comment: In `pivot_wider`, the "names" refer to column names. If you want a confusion matrix, then you want X to be column and Y to be rows (or vice versa). So when you pivot wider, you should just choose one value, ie: `names_from='x'`

Comment: Thanks @divibisan. That does indeed work on a regular R data frame! It still doesn't work on a sparklyr data frame, but that makes me think the issue is now a bug in sparklyr or the tidyr implementation for spark tables, and not a limitation in the pivot_wider function itself. I'm not sure what the best way to reformat this question in Stack Overflow for that situation is, though.

Comment: @AlphaBravo Probably the best thing to do would be to submit a new question, built around that. I don't know much about sparklyr, but is there a way to make a minimal example table that reproduces that error?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think I can phrase the question in a way other than a bug report, so I may just go to the sparklyr github and post an issue there.
It's pretty easy to turn the data posted above into a spark data frame and attempt the code. Just `library(sparklyr); install_spark(); sc <- spark_connect(master='local'); sdf <- copy_to(sc, df); sdf %>% pivot_wider(...)`